# A way of allocating multidimensional arrays dynamically

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

salute..

I am learning dynamic allocations for multidimensional arrays in a book and I found some ways for that, And now haven't problem in it.
But the author of the book shows us a way, but it doesn't work correctly. It is this:

```
pbeans = new double [3][4];         // Allocate memory for a 3x4 array
```

And this is the error:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int (*)[4]' to 'int *'
```

how should i define *pbeans* ( if this type of coding is legal)?

and what is the problem exactly?

Regards.

Comment: You might find [C++ Faqs](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.16) (and the FAQs immediately following it) helpful to understanding this.  By the way, this is a good thing to know about, but in general you should just use container classes (e.g., the standard template library).  And if you do use `new`, you'll usually want to wrap it in a container class or at least use a smart pointer.  Tenfour's code looks more complicated than Alnitak's because it is more production-ready; it protects you from memory leaks via [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in my [FAQ on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/):

```
double (*pbeans)[4];
pbeans = new double[3][4];

// ...

delete[] pbeans;
```

For the "C declarator impaired", you could make that more readable with a typedef:

```
typedef double row[4];

row *pbeans;
pbeans = new row[3];

// ...

delete[] pbeans;
```

But in C++, we prefer RAII containers over raw pointers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector<std::array<double, 4> > beans(3);
```

Note the complete absence of `delete[]` which makes this solution exception-safe.

Comment: I prefer this method because it also makes it very clear what your dimensions represent.

Comment: @C77: Note that the original error message already hinted at the type required for pbeans: `int (*)[4]`. It's just that many programmers don't have a clue what that funny combination of tokens could possibly mean. Curse you, C declarator syntax!

Comment: If the values are static then there is no new for new/delete. If both are dynamic you need to deallocate each row separately see p2DArray example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7459/

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate each dimension of the array separately:

```
double **pbeans = new double*[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    pbeans[i] = new double[4];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, So that is illegal and should i put the book in recycle bin? (:

Comment: well you _can_ just say `double pbeans[3][4]`, but that'll create the variable on the stack and not the heap.

Comment: Actually, you *can* create multidimensional arrays dynamically without allocating each dimension separately. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it that allocates the memory contiguously on the heap:

```
typedef double MyGrid[3][4];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyGrid& x = *(reinterpret_cast<Grid*>(new double[12]));
    ...
    x[1][2] = 0.3333;
    ...
    delete[] &x;
    return 0;
}
```

Which you could easily turn into a more generic solution:

```
template<typename T, int x, int y>
struct Array2D
{
    typedef T CArrayType[x][y];
    typedef CArrayType& RefType;
    static CArrayType& New()
    {
        return *(reinterpret_cast<CArrayType*>(new T[x * y]));
    }
    static void Delete(RefType x)
    {
        delete[] &x;
    }
};

typedef Array2D<double, 3, 4> MyGrid;// define your 2d array with 3 rows / 4 columns.

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyGrid::RefType j = MyGrid::New();
    ...
    j[1][2] = 0.3333;
    ...
    MyGrid::Delete(j);
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to just generate the elements in 1D (x*y), and cast it to a 2D array. But since array types are value types, you need to deal in pointers-to-arrays. Using a reference makes it almost transparent.

Boost probably has something like this but I don't know boost well enough to say...

Comment: @C77431: Unlike Alnitak's answer, this will allocate the multidimensional array contiguously in memory.  This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: No need to cast, see my answer.